# iPhone new lg ipone

Tags: google

I have a new lg , I dropped the phone and broke the screen I had it replaced and since then when I get a call the screen goes black I have to push the button on the back to get the screen to light up a to use the speaker phone, help phone tech can,t figure it out

Comment: Does the screen go black when you get a call or after you pick the call?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your proximity sensor [ the one beside the front camera ] is blocked or damaged. Try cleaning it or remove any screen protector that is not transparent.

Comment: That's what came in my mind. It definitely that proximity sensor that may have been covered or even damaged

Answer (score -3):

The behavior your experiencing is completely normal. Phones usually go black whilst in a call to avoid accidental pressing of buttons.

Comment: Didn't​ you understand his description, did you?

Comment: @esQmo_ Just a small correction for your grammar, you should say `You didn't understand..., did you?` instead of `Didn't you understand..., did you?`, or alternatively you can say `Didn't you understand...?`(remove `did you` from the last).

Comment: @iBug thanks for this, there was a bug in my brain. I usually speak French and other local languages :D (I learned something new today)